# Will old owner's title insurance be valid on refinance?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, real-estate, refinance, title-insurance

I was wondering: if I refinance my home, will I need a new owner's title insurance, or will the previous title insurance still be valid?

I suppose the new lender will require new lender's title insurance, but my owner's title insurance should still be valid. I have standard (non-enhanced) title insurance.

Comment: How recently did you have the previous title search and insurance done? I am not sure if that effects the answer, but it seems more likely to be accepted if the current insurance is recent

Comment: Have you read the terms of your policy?

Answer (score 3):

per [one of the title insurance company](https://www.firstam.com/ownership/title-insurance-policy-types/)

> If you're considering refinancing your mortgage, you may be surprised
>   to see that you are required to purchase a new lender's policy of
>   title insurance. This is because a lender's policy only provides
>   coverage for the life of a loan. When a home is refinanced, the life
>   of one loan ends and another begins. Thus, a new lender's policy for
>   title is required. Because an owner's policy provides coverage,
>   generally for as long as you or your heirs hold an interest in the
>   property, **there is no need to purchase a new owner's policy when
>   refinancing**.